# Trouble getting AutoMapper to convert Entity Framework Core with simple entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I think I've followed the directions at the URL https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html, but I'm getting this error I don't understand.

```
The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncEnumerable<MyApp.LectureRoomDto>'. Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
```

In my startup.cs I've added:

services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

And, in my ASP.NET Core 5 controller, I've got the following code.

```
public List<LectureRoomDto> GetSpeakers

  var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        cfg.CreateMap<LectureRoom, LectureRoomDto>());

  return context.LectureRooms.ProjectTo<LectureRoomDto>(configuration).ToList();
```

Where context is my dbContext that works as expected when I return IQueryable.

If there is a GitHub repo with a simple working example using EF Core and AutoMapper, that would be a big help.

Comment: https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityCore

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu unfortunately, that's EF6 and not ASP.NET Core, though, this one in the same github account is a help https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityDotNetCore-Pages/blob/master/ContosoUniversity/Pages/Students/Index.cshtml.cs

Comment: Sorry :) Note that it makes more sense to use `IMapper.ProjectTo` with DI, rather than the extension method.